# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [<>f__AnonymousType6`65[System.String,System.Decimal,System.Nullable`1

Tags: linq-to-sql, casting, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to hit my head to get out of this issue in which I'm not able to convert `System.Collections.Generic.List` to `IEnumerable`, below is my code :

```
IEnumerable<PY_History_TransactionTAB> FilteredReport;

var ReportData = db.PY_History_TransactionTAB
                 .Where(x => x.SystemCode == SysCode)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeCode);

FilteredReport = (IEnumerable<PY_History_TransactionTAB>)ReportData.Select(x => new
            {
                EmployeeCode = x.Key,
                H_SalaryDays = x.Sum(y => y.H_SalaryDays ?? 0),
                H_NET_Overtime = x.Sum(y => y.H_NET_Overtime),
                H_Overtime_Amount = x.Sum(y => y.H_Overtime_Amount),
                H_SL_Breakup1 = x.Sum(y => y.H_SL_Breakup1 ?? 0),
                H_SL_Breakup2 = x.Sum(y => y.H_SL_Breakup2 ?? 0),
                H_SL_Breakup3 = x.Sum(y => y.H_SL_Breakup3 ?? 0),
                H_OT_Allowance1 = x.Sum(y => y.H_OT_Allowance1 ?? 0),
                H_OT_Allowance2 = x.Sum(y => y.H_OT_Allowance2 ?? 0),
                H_OT_Allowance3 = x.Sum(y => y.H_OT_Allowance3 ?? 0),
                H_OT_Allowance4 = x.Sum(y => y.H_OT_Allowance4 ?? 0),                  
                H_OT_Allowance5 = x.Sum(y => y.H_OT_Allowance5 ?? 0)                   
            }).ToList();
```

When I run the application, it throws a runtime exception `System.InvalidCastException` at point of assignment to **FilteredReport** variable, by saying :

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`65
>    [System.String,System.Decimal,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal
>    ,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,
>    System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal]]' to type 'System.Collections
>    .Generic.IEnumerable`1[HrAndPayrollSystem.Models.PY_History_TransactionTAB]'."}

So, what I get is that I'm not going right, I need to find a right way, What should I do to get rid of this issue or what is the right way to convert a `List` to `IEnumerable`? Any Help will be deeply appreciated, Thanks in Advance!

**Update:**

Ok, René Vogt's answer is correct for the above issue, but then I encounter an another Exception `System.NotSupportedException` at the same point saying :

> The entity or complex type 
>    'HrAndPayrollSystem.Models.PY_History_TransactionTAB' 
>    cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you return an `List` of an *anonymous type*. So this `List<anonymousType>` is a totally different type than a `IEnumerable<HrAndPayrollSystem.Models.PY_History_TransactionTAB>`.

So you need to change your `Select` call to something like:

```
FilteredReport = (IEnumerable<PY_History_TransactionTAB>)ReportData.Select(x => 
    new PY_History_TransactionTAB // specify type!!
    {
       EmployeeCode = x.Key,
       // shortened for brevity... set properties appropriatly
    }).ToList();
```

Now the returned list is of type `List<PY_History_TransactionTAB>` which implements `IEnumerable<PY_History_TransactionTAB>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, this sounds very right, now I encounter another exception, please refer to my updated question.

Comment: @BilalAhmed, If this answer solved your problem it should be accepted. If you have another problem, then ask another question

Comment: @StephenMuecke My bad!

Comment: @StephenMuecke , Can you please navigate to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748691/how-to-include-the-groupby-elements-in-select-in-linq-to-sql-query)