# How to include the GroupBy() elements in Select() in Linq to Sql query

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a Linq to sql query:

```
IEnumerable<PY_History_TransactionTAB> FilteredReport;

var ReportData = db.PY_History_TransactionTAB.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(x => x.SystemCode == SysCode)
                 .GroupBy(x => new 
                 { 
                   x.EmployeeCode,
                   x.EmployeeMaster.Emp_FullName,
                   x.Designations.Title,
                   department = x.Departments.Title
                 });

FilteredReport = ReportData.Select(x => new PY_History_TransactionTAB
                {
                    EmployeeCode = x.Key.EmployeeCode,
                    H_SalaryDays = x.Sum(y => y.H_SalaryDays ?? 0),
                    H_NET_Overtime = x.Sum(y => y.H_NET_Overtime),
                    H_Overtime_Amount = x.Sum(y => y.H_Overtime_Amount),
                    H_SL_Breakup1 = x.Sum(y => y.H_SL_Breakup1 ?? 0),                       
                    H_OT_Allowance1 = x.Sum(y => y.H_OT_Allowance1 ?? 0),                      
                }).ToList();
```

Now, if I want to add the GroupBy member `x.EmployeeCode` in Select(), it takes it, and works fine, but I don't know how to include a navigation property `x.EmployeeMaster.Emp_FullName` to Select(), which is a next member of GroupBy(). I know that the model `PY_History_TransactionTAB` to which I am refering in Select() does not contain definition for `Emp_FullName` but it contains definition for a navigation property i.e. `EmployeeMaster`.

So, Is there a way to include a navigation property `x.EmployeeMaster.Emp_FullName` to the Select() so that I can access them in a strongly typed view?

Below is my View just for convenience :

```
@model IEnumerable<HrAndPayrollSystem.Models.PY_History_TransactionTAB>
        <tr>                
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Departments.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeMaster.Emp_FullName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designations.Title)
            </th>             
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.H_SalaryDays)
            </th>
            .
            .
            . // Other Elements
       </tr>
```

In the above View, I can access `model.EmployeeCode` but what I cannot access is `model.EmployeeMaster.Emp_FullName` and similarly other navigation properties.

So, my question is that how do I modify my linq to sql query to get the result view right?

Comment: You mean the `x.Key.Emp_FullName` part?

Comment: @JonHanna, Exactly, Yes and including other navigation properties `x.Key .Title` and `x.Key.department`, how to add all of such kind of properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your query this way :

```
FilteredReport = ReportData.Select(x => new PY_History_TransactionTAB
            {
                EmployeeCode = x.Key.EmployeeCode,
                EmployeeMaster = x.First().EmployeeMaster,
                .
                .    // other attributes
                .
            }).ToList();
```